# How to reference a property of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, gmail-api

I have the following results being returned by the Gmail API. What is the best way to use the JSON object?

```
{"result":{"messages":[{"id":"15d862a00074a324","threadId":"15d862a00074a324"},{"id":"15d8628752224d1b","threadId":"15d8628752224d1b"},{"id":"15d8231cfbca0608","threadId":"15d8231cfbca0608"},{"id":"15d812cb47b30f24","threadId":"15d812cb47b30f24"},{"id":"15d5e26548a7fe5b","threadId":"15d5e26548a7fe5b"}],"resultSizeEstimate":5},"body":"{\n \"messages\": [\n  {\n   \"id\": \"15d862a00074a324\",\n   \"threadId\": \"15d862a00074a324\"\n  },\n  {\n   \"id\": \"15d8628752224d1b\",\n   \"threadId\": \"15d8628752224d1b\"\n  },\n  {\n   \"id\": \"15d8231cfbca0608\",\n   \"threadId\": \"15d8231cfbca0608\"\n  },\n  {\n   \"id\": \"15d812cb47b30f24\",\n   \"threadId\": \"15d812cb47b30f24\"\n  },\n  {\n   \"id\": \"15d5e26548a7fe5b\",\n   \"threadId\": \"15d5e26548a7fe5b\"\n  }\n ],\n \"resultSizeEstimate\": 5\n}\n"}
```

I'm new to JSON objects, but I am familiar with PHP objects and arrays. I will be wanting to reference the `resultSizeEstimate` and iterate over the id's.

I was trying `JSON.stringify(response.resultSizeEstimate);`, but without any luck. What is the way for working with JSON objects? I can’t seem to find any standard way.

This is the function I am creating. *appendpre* just outputs to an element...

```
  function getUnread() {
    gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
      'userId': 'me',
      'q': 'is:unread in:inbox',
    }).then(function(response) {
      var unread = response;
      appendPre(JSON.stringify(response)); // Outputs JSON with string chars \n's
      console.log(JSON.parse(response)); // Errors as invalid JSON

    });
  }
```

---

Here is the working function for reference...

```
  function getUnread() {
    gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
      'userId': 'me',
      'q': 'is:unread in:inbox',
    }).then(function(response) {
      var unread = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( response ));
      appendPre(unread.result.resultSizeEstimate);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `JSON.parse` function. It accepts JSON content, and returns an object.

```js
let json = `
{
  "result": {
    "messages": [
      {"id":"15d862a00074a324","threadId":"15d862a00074a324"},
      {"id":"15d8628752224d1b","threadId":"15d8628752224d1b"},
      {"id":"15d8231cfbca0608","threadId":"15d8231cfbca0608"},
      {"id":"15d812cb47b30f24","threadId":"15d812cb47b30f24"},
      {"id":"15d5e26548a7fe5b","threadId":"15d5e26548a7fe5b"}
    ],
    "resultSizeEstimate": 5
  }
}`;

let obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log('resultSizeEstimate', obj.result.resultSizeEstimate);
console.log('message ids', obj.result.messages.map(msg => msg.id));
```

Comment: JSON.parse gives me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 ... Which a quick google tells me I'm already working with a json object.

Comment: Yes, because your json string contains invalid chars `\n` for example.

Comment: I've decreased json string, so now JSON.parse could parse it.

Comment: Thanks for you help with this but I still would like to know how to reference the properties for output. is it result.messages.id for each and result.resultSizeEstimate.

Comment: Result of `JSON.parse` is an object, so you could use its properties directly: `obj.result.resultSizeEstimate`. To get `id` of `messages` use native array method `map`.

Comment: Thanks alexmac, you have helped me find the answer. Edited the question with the revised function using JSON.parse as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Taking "resultSizeEstimate" as an example, you must read it from the "body" property.
Then convert the value of body from a string to an object. Here is the code:

```
var bodyStr=response.body;
var bodyObj=eval(bodyStr);//eval method can convert json str to an json object
var resultSizeEstimateVal=bodyObj.resultSizeEstimate;
```

The same thing we can do to get other properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to do that.

```
$json_data = '{"result":{"messages":[{"id":"15d862a00074a324","threadId":"15d862a00074a324"},{"id":"15d8628752224d1b","threadId":"15d8628752224d1b"},{"id":"15d8231cfbca0608","threadId":"15d8231cfbca0608"},{"id":"15d812cb47b30f24","threadId":"15d812cb47b30f24"},{"id":"15d5e26548a7fe5b","threadId":"15d5e26548a7fe5b"}],"resultSizeEstimate":5},"body":"{\n \"messages\": [\n  {\n   \"id\": \"15d862a00074a324\",\n   \"threadId\": \"15d862a00074a324\"\n  },\n  {\n   \"id\": \"15d8628752224d1b\",\n   \"threadId\": \"15d8628752224d1b\"\n  },\n  {\n   \"id\": \"15d8231cfbca0608\",\n   \"threadId\": \"15d8231cfbca0608\"\n  },\n  {\n   \"id\": \"15d812cb47b30f24\",\n   \"threadId\": \"15d812cb47b30f24\"\n  },\n  {\n   \"id\": \"15d5e26548a7fe5b\",\n   \"threadId\": \"15d5e26548a7fe5b\"\n  }\n ],\n \"resultSizeEstimate\": 5\n}\n"};
$data = json_decode($json_data);
echo $data->resultSizeEstimate;
```

*json_decode* will take a JSON string and then convert it into a PHP variable.